Unpin cloth at a specific frame using vertex modifier
I am trying to generate folded cloth state in blender using python API. But for which I need to ensure that pin of cloth is released after a specific frame . But I am not able to do it till now . I would be helpful to any suggestion.
def generate_cloth_state(cloth):
# Move cloth slightly above the table and simulate a drop
if cloth is None:
    cloth = make_cloth()  # Assuming make_cloth() is a function to create the cloth object

# Randomly place the cloth in space
dx = np.random.uniform(0, 0.7) * random.choice((-1, 1))
dy = np.random.uniform(0, 0.7) * random.choice((-1, 1))
dz = np.random.uniform(0.4, 0.8)
cloth.location = (dx, dy, dz)
cloth.rotation_euler = (0, 0, random.uniform(0, np.pi))  # Random rotation about x/y axes

# Remove existing 'Pinned' group if it exists and create a new one
if 'Pinned' in cloth.vertex_groups:
    cloth.vertex_groups.remove(cloth.vertex_groups['Pinned'])

pinned_group = cloth.vertex_groups.new(name='Pinned')

# Randomly select one vertex to pin
n = random.choice(range(1, 2))  # Number of vertices to pin (choose 1)
subsample = sample(range(len(cloth.data.vertices)), n)
pinned_group.add(subsample, 1.0, 'REPLACE')

# Set the cloth modifier to use the 'Pinned' vertex group
cloth.modifiers["Cloth"].settings.vertex_group_mass = 'Pinned'

# Create the 'Empty' vertex group (not used for pinning but might be useful later)
empty_group = cloth.vertex_groups.new(name="Empty")

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='VERTEX_WEIGHT_MIX')
cloth.modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].vertex_group_a = 'Pinned'
cloth.modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].vertex_group_b = 'Empty'
cloth.modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].mix_set = 'OR' 
cloth.modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].mix_mode = 'ADD' 



cloth.modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].mask_constant = 0
cloth.keyframe_insert(data_path='modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].mask_constant',frame=0)

cloth.modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].mask_constant = 1
cloth.keyframe_insert(data_path='modifiers["VertexWeightMix"].mask_constant',frame=50)


bpy.context.scene.frame_start = 0
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 100  # Adjust as needed

return cloth

I am trying to do the dynamic operation using vertex mix modifiers.

You might find this technique useful: Assign vertex group in Geometry Nodes (v3.3)

@MarkusvonBroady Might as well answer this with python implementation part
